# Let's get critical: Oct 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Update Search Plugin from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3.x](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4370/migrate-search-plugin-from-joomla-2-5-to-joomla-3-x)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Detect current template style](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4410/detect-current-template-style)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [List All Categories (com_content/views/categories) alternative layout not working](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4388/list-all-categories-com-content-views-categories-alternative-layout-not-workin)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Delete <li> tag of "Forgot Password", "Registration"](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4367/delete-li-tag-of-forgot-password-registration)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How (re)set password for admin after migration from 1.5?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/how-reset-password-for-admin-after-migration-from-1-5)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is it possible to display a list of category "grand children"?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/is-it-possible-to-display-a-list-of-category-grand-children)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [No notification to update to latest Joomla version](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4468/no-notification-to-update-to-latest-joomla-version)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Mavik Thumbnails for Joomla 3](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4413/mavik-thumbnails-for-joomla-3)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Why Joomla 3 add Canonical tag to current page and made it unindexable?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4442/why-joomla-3-add-canonical-tag-to-current-page-and-made-it-unindexable)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Joomla capabilities for content authoring](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4296/joomla-capabilities-for-content-authoring)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---